# Change home directory on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I am using some software that doesn't react well when run in a directory path with a space in its name. I created my Windows 7 account as "JOHN DOE" and so now my Documents and Settings has a space on it. Should I change my login name to "JOHN" ? If so, how do I change my home directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the program being run from within your documents and settings folder in the first place? Might it be easier to just move the program to something like `C:\stupidprogram\ `?

Comment: Because I am compiling with mingw's MSys program and I'm building the programs in my home directory. Configure scripts run libtool, which doesn't work well when there are spaces in paths because it calls sub-shells without properly quoting. Aren't you glad you asked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new account, then copy your old user profile over to the new account, when you are happy with the new user account delete the old one.

Scroll down to "copying your user profile"

This article is for XP, but the instructions are very similar for Vista/W7

http://www.lockergnome.com/it/2004/12/15/get-it-done-recover-a-damaged-windows-xp-user-profile/

There may be other documents you need to copy and paste from the old user documents folders, be sure you have everything copied before you delete the old account.

See "Copy files to new user profile:" under Step B
http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2010/09/how-to-fix-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-7/

You can change the account name, but doing this will Not change the name of the user account folder, it cannot be changed, you have to create a new user account with the name you need.

.

Comment: Looks more complicated than it is.